# Development Provisioning profile is gone after import

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I imported my Developer Profile from one mac to another. 
Here are the steps I did:

IN Mac1:

1. Xcode-> Preferences
2. selected my team -> Export Developer accounts...

IN Mac2:

1. Xcode-> Preferences
2. selected my team -> Import Developer accounts...

Then I went back to apple member center I found out that my Development Provisioning profile is missing. While it was available before the export of the developer account.

Why did it delete it and how do I get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to regenerate a provisional profile